# python selenium webscraping - cannot obtain data

Tags: python, selenium

I came across a website where I am hoping to scrape some data from. But the site seems to be un-scrapable for my limited Python knowledge. When using driver.find_element_by_xpath, I usually run into timeout exceptions.

Using the code I provided below, I hope to click on the first result and go to a new page. On the new page, I want to scrape the product title, and pack size. But no matter how I try it, I cannot even get Python to click the right thing for me. Let alone scraping the data. Can someone help out?

My desired output is:

Tris(triphenylphosphine)rhodium(I) chloride, 98% 
190420010
1 GR     87.60
5 GR     367.50

---

These are the codes I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "http://www.acros.com/"
cas = "14694-95-2"  # need to select for the appropriate one

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

country = driver.find_element_by_name("ddlLand")
for option in country.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
    if option.text == "United States":
        option.click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type = submit]").click() 

choice = driver.find_element_by_name("_ctl1:DesktopThreePanes1:ThreePanes:_ctl4:ddlType")
for option in choice.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
    if option.text == "CAS registry number":
        option.click()

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("_ctl1_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes__ctl4_tbSearchString")
inputElement.send_keys(cas)
driver.find_element_by_id("_ctl1_DesktopThreePanes1_ThreePanes__ctl4_btnGo").click()
```

Comment: In the long run, I will be writing a for loop that takes in a bunch of cas #'s and output the result, so I want my code to be general to allow for automation.

Comment: Once you navigate to a different page (which typically happens after calling the `click` method ), all previous elements that you have in memory are potentially invalid (AKA "stale"). I suggest that you add `break` after you call this method inside each of the `for` loops in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as presented works fine for me, in that it directs the instance of Firefox to http://www.acros.com/DesktopModules/Acros_Search_Results/Acros_Search_Results.aspx?search_type=CAS&SearchString=14694-95-2 which shows the search results.

If you locate the iframe element on that page:

<iframe id="searchAllFrame" allowtransparency="" background-color="transparent" frameborder="0" width="1577" height="3000" scrolling="auto" src="http://newsearch.chemexper.com/misc/hosted/acrosPlugin/center.shtml?query=14694-95-2&searchType=cas&currency=&country=NULL&language=EN&forGroupNames=AcrosOrganics,FisherSci,MaybridgeBB,BioReagents,FisherLCMS&server=www.acros.com"></iframe>

and use driver.switch_to.frame to switch to that frame then I think data you want should be scrapable from there, for example:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='searchAllFrame']"))
```

You can then carry on using the driver as usual to find elements within that iframe. (I think `switch_to_frame` works similarly, but is deprecated.)

(I can't seem to find a decent link to docs for switch_to, [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) isn't all that helpful.

Comment: Hi can you elaborate on how I do this? I've never used switch_to and do not understand much about switching frames. I'll do some research

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I never knew about switching frames. I was able to solve the problem by calling driver.switch_to_frame!!!!!